# HTTP Digest Own Form JQuery Mobile

Tags: php, ajax, jquery-mobile, authentication, digest-authentication

I am trying to replace the "Authentication Required" box that appears with authentication with a custom form for a username and password in JQuery Mobile.I am currently using HTTP Digest that I found from a tutorial (http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php). I am using AJAX with JQuery mobile to load up a PHP resource that logs in to the system and have got it half working. What I've tried so far is:

```
url: 'http://username:password@domain/resource/',
```

and

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://url/resource/',
    username: "username",
    password: "password",
    contentType: "text",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data)
    {
     alert("Success");
    },
    error: function (response) 
    {
    alert("Fail");
    }
      });
```

These both work when I am viewing the website on my desktop however when I view it on a smartphone (tried on iPhone and S4) it will instead show the default "Authentication Required" box and not take any of the details I provide in my own custom form. I wanted to know what the problem could be as I am pulling my hair out over this.

Thanks

Comment: try adding `data-ajax="false"` to form container.

Comment: Just tried this and the same problem happens. The form will work on a computer but when using a smartphone it prompts for a username and password in the default authentication box.

Comment: it works well on desktop with jQM?

Comment: Yes, on a desktop the custom form I have made will take in the information and use that as the username and password, but when on a smartphone, once the users hits the submit button, even if the details are correct, the Authentication required box comes up making them enter in the details.